# Call recording, really strange behaviour

Tags: android, call, audio-recording

The task is to record a phone call.

Everything else apart from the following code is working: incoming call event, outgoing call event, call rejected and so on, so my problem is during the audio recording.

The code:

```java
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

boolean AAC_SUPPORTED = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 10;

if (AAC_SUPPORTED) {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
} else {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(8000);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(12200);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
}
```

Here comes the strange inexplicable part:

Person A calls Person B. In Person A phone the recorded .mp4 file is just perfect. The audio is clear and loud both sides. But then Person B calls Person A. We are still on the phone of Person A. The same code for audio recording is running but this time the other person's voice is not recorded or recorded in really bad quality.

So the outgoing call is just perfect, but in the incoming call the other person voice is not recording, regardless the same code is executed.

The OS version in both phones is 4.4.4

I tested all params for setAudioSource();

With and without:

```java
mediaRecorder.setAudioSamplingRate(44100);
mediaRecorder.setAudioEncodingBitRate(96000);
```

I run the code from inside a Receiver which is declared with this intent-filter:

```xml
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_ANSWER"/>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Does anybody have a clue where the problem is?

I tested the scenario with another Call Recorder app and everything is just fine. So it is not device specific. There must be something I do wrong.